# NFC-V Tag not discovered by Sharp Aquos Phone EX SH-04E

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I wrote an android application based on the NFC Technology which reads/write the data from a NFC-V tag (ST microelectronics M24LR64-R series). I checked the application on Galazy nexus and found that it is working. But when i tried the same on Sharp Aquos Phone EX SH-04E (Japanese phone) then found that it is not working. Even the detection of NFC is not happening (no beep sound). I checked on internet and found the same case for Nexus 4/10 but Nexus 4/10 is using the Broadcom NFC chip due to that they are not detecting the NFC-V tags. A bug is already logged for the same.

Now my question is that the is there any other reason why Sharp Aquos Phone EX SH-04E is not detecting the NFC-V tag. Because when I searched on net i did not which Sharp Aquos Phone EX SH-04E is using what kind of chip whetehr it is NXP type or Broadcom type.